# Problem BibTeX compilation

Tags: bibtex

I have a paper with many different authors, I don't know why it doesn't want to compile, any idea why ?

```
@article{Spider_paper_2018,
    author    = {Yu T., Zhang R., Yang K., Yasunaga M.,
                 Wang D., Li Z., Ma J., Li I., Yao Q.,
                 Roman S., Zhang Z. and Radev D.R.},
    title     = {Spider: A Large-Scale Human-Labeled Dataset for Complex and Cross-Domain
    Semantic Parsing and Text-to-SQL Task},
    journal   = {CoRR},
    volume    = {abs/1809.08887},
    year      = {2018},
    url       = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08887},
    archivePrefix = {arXiv},
    eprint    = {1809.08887},
    timestamp = {Fri, 05 Oct 2018 11:34:52 +0200},
    biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/journals/corr/abs-1809-08887},
    bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

Comment: if you want help with an error, it helps if you say what the error message is.

Comment: the author entry is wrong though, authors should be separated by and not by commas.

Answer (score 1):

The bib entry can be directly downloaded from the URL in the field `biburl` and it results in

```
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1809-08887,
  author    = {Tao Yu and
               Rui Zhang and
               Kai Yang and
               Michihiro Yasunaga and
               Dongxu Wang and
               Zifan Li and
               James Ma and
               Irene Li and
               Qingning Yao and
               Shanelle Roman and
               Zilin Zhang and
               Dragomir R. Radev},
  title     = {Spider: {A} Large-Scale Human-Labeled Dataset for Complex and Cross-Domain
               Semantic Parsing and Text-to-SQL Task},
  journal   = {CoRR},
  volume    = {abs/1809.08887},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08887},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint    = {1809.08887},
  timestamp = {Fri, 05 Oct 2018 11:34:52 +0200},
  biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/journals/corr/abs-1809-08887},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

As you see, the authors are separated by `and` and not by commas.

There are a couple of fixes to do

1. change the key from `DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1809-08887` to `Spider_paper_2018`
2. change the title from

   ```
   title     = {Spider: {A} Large-Scale Human-Labeled Dataset for Complex and Cross-Domain
              Semantic Parsing and Text-to-SQL Task},
   ```

   to

   ```
   title     = {Spider: {A} Large-Scale Human-Labeled Dataset for Complex and Cross-Domain
              Semantic Parsing and Text-to-{SQL} Task},
   ```

   in order that “SQL” doesn't risk to be lowercased.

Or just change your entry into

```
@article{Spider_paper_2018,
    author    = {Yu, T. and Zhang, R. and Yang, K. and Yasunaga, M. and
                 Wang, D. and Li, Z. and Ma, J. and Li, I. and Yao, Q. and
                 Roman, S. and Zhang, Z. and Radev, D.R.},
    title     = {Spider: {A} Large-Scale Human-Labeled Dataset for Complex and Cross-Domain
    Semantic Parsing and Text-to-{SQL} Task},
    journal   = {CoRR},
    volume    = {abs/1809.08887},
    year      = {2018},
    url       = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08887},
    archivePrefix = {arXiv},
    eprint    = {1809.08887},
    timestamp = {Fri, 05 Oct 2018 11:34:52 +0200},
    biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/journals/corr/abs-1809-08887},
    bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

Note the format for authors: it should be “Family name, Given name”, besides authors being separated by `and`.